# getApplicationDocumentsDirectory failing on Browsers (other possible approaches)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My app uses path_provider's `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` to get the documents folder so I can save and edit some json files. That works fine on Android and iOS but I am struggling to get that to work on Chrome/Any Browser.

Is there an alternative?
This is how I use at the moment:

```
  static loadDirectory() async =>
      directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

and then (for example):

```
  removeFile(String fileName) {
    File file = File("${directory.path}/$fileName.json");
    if (file.existsSync()) file.delete();
  }
```

What's the approach for save/maintain files when dealing with browsers (I am considering to move my app to a website)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a small amount of data you can use `shared_preferences` package. This package supports all platforms and you don't need to deal with different platforms by yourself.

```dart
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await prefs.setString('data', json);
final String? json = prefs.getString('data');
```

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: I think I have around 3 json files to edit/save. But they might contain around 1000 rows, is that still the prefered approach?

Comment: Since this package uses local storage in web, I think files under 5MB should be fine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/9455518

Answer (score 0):

@Icaroto On web, `path_provider` can't directly access the file system like on Android and iOS due to security restrictions. For basic tasks like saving JSON files, opt for `LocalStorage`. For complex file operations, utilize **web APIs** for file handling.